# Non-uniform averages for ergodic theorem

Tags: measure-theory, ergodic-theory

**Theorem** (Birkhoff) Let $(E, \mathcal{E}, \mu)$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space and let $T : E \to E$ be a measure-preserving transformation. Suppose that $f \in L^1(\mu)$. Then, the approximations:

$$F_n : =\frac{\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} f \circ T^k}{n}$$

converge almost everywhere to a $T$-invariant integrable function $F:E \to E$

In this theorem, we average the functions $f \circ T^k$ uniformly, but we may note that convergence also holds in some other cases; for instance, if we define:

$$G_n : =\frac{\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (1+(-1)^k) f \circ T^k}{n}$$

Of course, this particular example can also be proved with Birkhoff by considering $T^2$. However, it raises the question of which coefficients are sufficient for convergence of the ergodic averages.

**Question**: for each $n$, let $(s^{(n)}_k)_{1 \le k \le n}$ be a vector of non-negative real numbers with $\sum_k s^{(n)}_k = 1$. Suppose that we define:

$$H_n = \sum_k s_k^{(n)} f \circ T^k$$

Which conditions on the family of vectors $(s^{(n)})$ are sufficient for $H_n \to F $ a.e.?